Windows taskbar show correctly on one window, exists but is empty/doesn't work on others
I'm running windows 11 enterprise and have turned on the feature to show taskbars across all monitors.  Whenever I log into my machine I see the taskbar running correctly the top right of my 4 monitors.  The other 3 monitors have a grey bar around on the bottom of the screen that sort of looks like a completely empty taskbar.  While in this state auto scrolling of some prompts like cmd prompt and git-bash doesn't function right, It seems to think I have more screen real-estate then I really have and so the last line or two get cut off.
If I double click on the one functional taskbar (or I believe press the windows key) my computer will freeze for a minutes and then all four taskbars will start working correctly and scrolling will function correctly...usually.
Is there a way to get my taskbars to function correctly from the beginning?  How are they getting so confused.
I'm connecting to this machine via remote desktop, not sure if that would mater.
